# Python Input .txt Files

Tags: python, file-io

I am learning Python independently, more specifically on File I|O.

To load a text file, I am taught to use the .readline() function, with the follow codes.

```
in_file = open (filename, "rt")

while True:
    in_line = in_file.readline ()

    if not in_line:
        break

    in_line = in_line [:-1]
    name, number = in_line.split (",")
    dic [name] = number

in_file.close ()
```

I am trying to understand what is going on with the codes, and I have trouble understanding the line:

```
if not in_line:
    break
```

I understand that it is required to break out of the 'while' loop, but how does it actually work?

Comment: Hint: Try to add `print('{!r}'.format(in_line))` before the `if not in_line:` to see what's going on.

Comment: This is the second question this morning using this technique. Where are you learning it? `while True: in_file.readline()` is a lot more verbose than it needs to be, not when you can just do `for in_line in in_file:` and never have to test for the end condition.

Comment: @tripleee: that's just as overly verbose as this whole file reading technique. What's wrong with `print(repr(in_line))`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, right you are.

Comment: Wikibooks for me. I am almost finished. Any good books I should learn from which teaches OOP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`file.readline()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) returns an empty string when there are no more lines to read:

> When *size* is not 0, an empty string is returned only when EOF is encountered immediately.

The condition tests for that end-condition, to end the loop. `if not in_line:` is true only if `in_line` is an empty string. All 'empty' values in Python are considered false, and the `not` operator turns false into `True`. See the [*Truth Value Testing* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> [...]
>
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.

Using a `while` loop is actually overly verbose here. You can read a file much more succintly by using a `for` loop, making the file an iterator:

```
for in_line in in_file:
    in_line = in_line.rstrip('\n')
```

It is not guaranteed that a line ends in a newline; the `str.rstrip()` call above removes it *only if it is actually there*.

Last but not least, you can use the file object as a *context manager*; the passing an open file object to the `with` statement makes makes sure that the file is closed again automatically when the block is done, even if an exception occurs:

```
with open(filename, "rt") as in_file:
    for in_line in in_file:
        in_line = in_line.rstrip('\n')
```

and no separate `in_file.close()` call is needed anymore.

Also see the [*Methods of File Objects* section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If `in_line` is false there was no line left to read, the `break` will break the while loop so the program can end when there is nothing more to read from the file.